# Bring up user information when on User Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

i want to create a visualforce page for community cloud that will show the logged in user's details. the following code just shows empty fields:

```
<apex:page standardController="User" showHeader="true">
  <apex:form >
          <apex:pageBlock >
              <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" value="Edit"/>
              </apex:pageBlockButtons>
              <apex:pageBlockSection title="User Detail">
                  <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.User.FieldSets.InspectorUserMain}" var="f">
                      <apex:outputField value="{!User[f]}" >
                          <apex:facet name="header">User Detail</apex:facet>
                          <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
                      </apex:outputField>
                  </apex:repeat>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>
              <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information">
                  <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.User.FieldSets.InspectorAdditionalData}" var="f">
                      <apex:outputField value="{!User[f]}" >
                          <apex:facet name="header">Additional Information</apex:facet>
                          <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
                      </apex:outputField>
                  </apex:repeat>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>
          </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Any idea how to tell the page to show the logged in user's details???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. You can use the `$User` [Global Variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm) to get the running user Id. With it, you can run a script that redirects to include this Id when it is left off.

```
<apex:page standardController="User">
    <apex:outputText value="{!User.Name}" />
    <script>
        (function (w) {
            "use strict";
            if (!w.location.search || w.location.search.indexOf('id=') < 0) {
                w.location.search = '?id={!$User.Id}';
            }
        }(window));
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

In theory, you should be able to do it without Javascript using the `action` attribute on your `<apex:page>` tag, possibly in conjunction with a controller extension, but I wasn't able to whip up a POC for that.